# Magnolia: Range request doesn't serve content when cache filter enabled resulting in Facebook Sharing not to work

Tags: magnolia, share-open-graph, range-header

When sending an HTTP request with a `Range` header to Magnolia I get a Response with 
`Content-Length: 0`:

```
        curl -I -X GET \
          http://localhost:8080/ \
          -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
          -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
          -H 'Range: bytes=0-2000'
        HTTP/1.1 206
        Set-Cookie: SID=C36D961EC92D152724BBCD0C34EC6536; Path=/; HttpOnly
        X-Magnolia-Registration: Registered
        Accept-Ranges: bytes
        Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
        ETag: 8B4901E7DD862E5E74287A0F538DCDDFEB78DE77
        Content-Range: bytes 0-2000/23529
        Content-Encoding: gzip
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        Pragma: no-cache
        Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
        Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:52:49 GMT
        Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
        Content-Length: 0
        Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:52:49 GMT
```

However, when I disable the Magnolia Cache Module I get the expected response:

`/server/filters/cache` -> `enabled: false`

```
        curl -I -X GET \
          http://localhost:8080/ \
          -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
          -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
          -H 'Range: bytes=0-2000'
        HTTP/1.1 206
        Set-Cookie: SID=FF557EC1F0653E5CBD81A57D599091AE; Path=/; HttpOnly
        X-Magnolia-Registration: Registered
        Accept-Ranges: bytes
        ETag: 2A9DE4F4B2ACDDE22BAC3C07784CD65693574B67
        Content-Range: bytes 0-2000/2147483647
        Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
        Content-Length: 2001
        Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:51:49 GMT
```

I got the problem that the Facebook crawler isn't able to detect any open graph meta tags when trying to crawl my website. I think the reason is the above described problem with sending range requests to Magnolia (What the [Facebook crawler](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/?locale=en_US) does).

My Open Graph tags are properly set (Working for [opengraphcheck](https://opengraphcheck.com/) and Twitter Card Validator).

I'm using Magnolia 5.7.1.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ - is that author or public instance?

Comment: @Jan it's the public instance

Comment: hmm, and when you flush the cache and then try to curl the page? What do you get? Is it still broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest work around is to configure request header voter to bypass cache when range header is present.
See [RequestHeaderPatternSimpleVoter](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.7/apidocs/info/magnolia/voting/voters/RequestHeaderPatternSimpleVoter.html) and/or [RequestHeaderPatternRegexVoter](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.7/apidocs/info/magnolia/voting/voters/RequestHeaderPatternRegexVoter.html) for more details on how to set it, but I would still consider it workaround and not final solution.

It seems weird that such thing should be happening. Could you replicate it against e.g. https://demo.magnolia-cms.com?

Comment: Using the ```RequestHeaderPatternRegexVoter``` resolves the issue, thanks! However, as you mention this is a workaround for an unexpected behavior which should not be happening. 

I could not reproduce the issue on https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com which is running on Magnolia 6.1.4. Maybe my older version (5.7.1) causes the issue. I reported the issue to Magnolia support.

Comment: Thanks, resolves my issue too, inserting an url in a LinkedIn entry failed before (error in LinkedIn Post Inspector). Magnolia 5.7.9. Checking now Magnolia support.